# Definition of Beit Hakneset area [with respect to tachanun]

Tags: halacha, marriage, synagogue, brit-milah, tachanun

[Shulchan Aruch O"CH 131:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=173) says that we don't say Tachanun where there is a Chatan in the syagogue:  (see also this [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9810/when-does-a-chosson-free-the-congregation-from-saying-tachanun)) (Note: I mention here Chatan because it's clearly mentioned, but AFAIK it would be the same law with a Mohel, a Sandak, or the child's father.)

> ולא כשיש שם חתן

1) Does this mean that as long as there is a chatan somewhere in the synagogue building - no one in the building says tachanun?? [If not...]

2) What if there are several rooms in the synagogue where prayers are held and the Chatan is in one of them - what then?

[The next couple of questions slightly stray from my original one... but while I'm here...]

3) If the Chatan is not participating in the minyan but just happens to be in the synagogue when the minyan reaches tanachun - would we say tachanun?

4) If one prays with Chatan neither within a Synagogue nor with a minyan - does one say Tachanun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions 1 and 2:

[O Ch 131 (4) MB [24]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=23) says that those davenning in the courtyard which does not have a separate ark or amud are included in the same law as the main synagogue with respect to not saying tachanun when there is a choson or a bris.

(The “Dirshu” MB in note 21 on O Ch 131 (4) MB [24] writes that the Ladies Area “Ezras Noshim” is considered part of the shul. [My note: for example if there are no ladies, and men are davenning there.])

Question 3:

Piskei Teshuvos page 71, says the custom is to be lenient and not say tachanun when the choson is present in the shul but not davenning with the minyan.

Question 4:

Piskei Teshuvos page 71, says the custom not to say tachanun with a choson is only when there is a minyan davenning. Individuals davenning without a minyan are not freed from saying tachanun.

The following may also be of interest:

1)  [**K’hal Adath Jeshurun – Breuer’s**](http://guesswhoscoming2dinner.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/kaj-breuers-tachanun-lights.html). On days when Tachanun is not said it is the minhag in K’hal Adath Jeshurun to indicate this omission by illuminating lights on special sconces installed for this purpose, located on the mizrach wall. One Light is illuminated when there tachanun is not said because of a Bris or a Chosson.

2)  [**770 Headquarters of Lubavitch in NY**](http://crownheights.info/general/6814/new-system-informing-if-there-is-a-choson-in-770/) 
“Thursday, (7 Jun 07) a new system has just been installed in 770 informing if there is a Choson in shul, so you would know if you have to say Tachnun or not.

“If you are a Choson during sheva brochos, you are kindly asked to walk up to the umud and choose the amount of time they will be in 770 and the light will remain on till you leave. In an event that you leave earlier you can go and shut it off.”

See the interesting discussion on this innovation and pictures.

Comment: Why "for example if there are no ladies"? Do women not say _tachanun_? +1, though: good answer.

Comment: @msh210 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/248/759

Comment: @msh10 point taken. My supposition was that there is no chiddush to say that the Ezras Noshim is considered part of the shul when ladies are davenning there. Where else should they be? Thank you Double AA.